# how to sharepoint display columns content into several languages

Tags: 2010, multilingual

I have created a site, installed my language packs, created the term store service and created some terms in multi-language (Persian and English). I then created a site in which, I created a new list and columns for it. I created resource for multi-language and show list/column name to switch language.

The problem is..... is there a way for my user defined **content column** to switch language the same way the values can use the term store?

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is that variations are designed for publishing sites/p[ages so there is no easy way to do it. If you happen to be using variations then you can create a separate list in each variation site and have the appropriate translated content in each list.

Otherwise you will need to have a single list with different content columns for each language and develop custom functionality to view the content depending on language.

Alternatively add one extra column in the list called language and then filter the list contents on this column, producing a view for each language.

No straight forward way though.